# Dynamically adding elements on a panel with autoscroll

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I added dynamically elements on a panel with autscroll on. The element exceed the visible area of the panel so that means it should trigger the autoscroll but that is not my case. But when I tried to add the element manually(drag and drop) the autoscroll works fine. In short the autoscroll appears only in static but not in dynamically added elements

I tried the `.refresh()`, `.update` also not sure with these `.suspendLayout()`, `.resumeLayout()` may be I did it wrong. In Windows from btw

```cs
table_module_day[] tbl_day = new table_module_day[6];

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{                
    tbl_day[i] = new table_module_day();                
    if (showType == 1)
    {
        tbl_day[i].setPanelname(dataOf);
        tbl_day[i].setSection(tempid);
    }               
    this.table_container.Controls.Add(tbl_day[i]);
    string day = "";
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            tbl_day[i].Location = new Point(898, 3);
            day = "Saturday";
            break;
        case 1:
            tbl_day[i].Location = new Point(719, 3);
            day = "Friday";
            break;
        case 2:
            tbl_day[i].Location = new Point(540, 3);
            day = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 3:
            tbl_day[i].Location = new Point(361, 3);
            day = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 4:
            tbl_day[i].Location = new Point(182, 3);
            day = "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 5:
            tbl_day[i].Location = new Point(3, 3);
            day = "Monday";
            break;
    }
    tbl_day[i].Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top|AnchorStyles.Bottom);
    tbl_day[i].setDay(day);
    tbl_day[i].addClass();
}
```

Comment: Windows Forms, WPF, Xamarin, something else?

Comment: Windows Forms sir

Comment: Remove the anchor. If you want a dynamic layout, use a TableLayoutPanel and dock the child control in its Cells.

Comment: @Jimi didn't work =( my problem is the scroll is not working when a control is added via code but when I drag it manual to the panel the scrollbar works

Comment: If the horizontal Scrollbar doesn't appear, then your Panel container's `AutoScroll` property is not set.  Otherwise, you'd see it. You should specify the *nature* of this container. If it's a FlowLayoutPanel and it's docked, the behavior changes.

Comment: @Jimi just the same the scrollbar appears when I drag the control from the tooltip but when the control is added via code it doesn't.

Comment: @Jimi its out of the problem the scrollbars works fine IF controls are added into it and the size of the child control is beyond the visible area of the panel BUT if it's added via code(source above) it scroll don't work. In short if manually added the scroll recognize it that there is a content beyond the visible area, but not via code. Hope we're on the same page =(

Comment: No, we're not. The only way for the ScrollBar not to appear is because the AutoScroll is set to false or the Container expands when you add child controls to it, so the AutoSize property is set to true, when it obviously shouldn't.

Comment: @Jimi probably just said it that it works when I added it manually so it means the Autoscroll is true and the size of the container is fix. I think you're not getting the point? =(